# Question from Evans’ book.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

[image]

I have confused by the last inequality $u(x)\geq\dfrac{1}{2^{n(N+1)}}u(y)$. I try to figure out how he gets it and here is my thought:

I know that $\bar{V}\subset\{B_{i}\}_{i=1}^{N}$, so for all $x,y\in V$, there exists $B_{i},B_{j}$ such that $x\in B_{i}$ and $y\in B_{j}\ (i<j)$. Also, $B_{i}\cap B_{i-1}\neq\emptyset$, therefore I choose points $y_{i},\cdots,y_{j}$ from balls $B_{i},\cdots,B_{j}$ such that $|y_{k}-y_{k-1}|<\frac{r}{2},\ k=i+1,\cdots,j+1$.

Then I calculate $u(x)$ the same way as the book:$$\begin{aligned}
u(x)=&\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-}_{B(x,r)}udz\geq\dfrac{1}{\alpha(n)r^{n}}\int_{B(y_{i},\frac{r}{2})}udz\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-}_{B(y_{i},\frac{r}{2})}udz=\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}u(y_{i}).\\
\end{aligned}$$
Similarily, $u(y_{i})\geq\dfrac{1}{2^{n}}u(y_{i+1})\Rightarrow u(x)\geq\dfrac{1}{2^{2n}}u(y_{i+1})$.

Continue then I obtain $u(x)\geq\dfrac{1}{2^{n(j+i)}}u(y)\geq\dfrac{1}{2^{n(N+1)}}u(y)$ which is exactly the last inequality.

Is my thought correct? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I don't have the time to verify the details, but the main idea (iterating the inequality on a chain of balls) is definitely right.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thanks for your response!